# Django server killed frequently

Tags: python, linux, django, virtualenv

I'm developing a Django project and testing it on a dedicated server. 
The project is running on:

- django 1.9.6
- virtualenv
- python 2.7
- cx_Oracle 5.2.1

---

**Running**

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.30.17:8080 &
```

all goes well. Project running and with `ps aux` I get, for example:

```
root      8437  0.0  0.9 461108 39036 pts/0    S    15:17   0:00 python manage.py runserver 192.168.30.17:8080
root      8861  3.5  1.5 1319364 64232 pts/0   Sl   15:24   0:14 /new_esmart/esmart_env/bin/python manage.py runserver 192.168.30.17:8080
```

---

**THE PROBLEM: Frequently server goes down with no error showed on shell**. I simply receive: 
`Killed`

How can I retrieve more information to find the cause of this killing?

**NOTE**: No gunicorn et similia solution right now. I have to use django server  for the next hours

**Temporary solution**

A script that respawns the server when killed

```
until python manage.py runserver 192.168.30.17:8080; do
   echo "Server Django crashed with exit code $. Respawning ...">&2
   sleep 2
done
```

Comment: that critical moment ended. Now I'm running gunicorn on production!

Comment: running Gunicorn ... but with this big problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/807721/prevent-gunicorn-from-loading-slowly-after-an-inactive-period

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on the django development server 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone
>   through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s
>   gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web
>   servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production
>   environment is outside the scope of Django.)

Of course it get's killed frequently, it's not designed to be kept running for long hours. Set up one of the standard solutions such as gunicorn+nginx or apache+uswgi etc.

Comment: I know, but right now I have to use django server instead gunicorn (already set but very slow)

Comment: There's absolutetly no reason that you have to use it and it's definitely a big no no and worse still you are letting your website's users down by running such a system by potentially exposing their data

Comment: @Sam if you have a dedicated server you can get Django running with wsgi on apache in literally minutes, this will save you on serving static files with proper caching and allow for many many connections without worrying about the server being "killed."