# Django dev server web page shuts down every 24 hours

Tags: django, manage.py

New Django learner here!
I have a Django web page that I want to run continuously. 
This is what I do to start the server in cmd.

```
manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

This starts the server and then I keep it running in the background. When I start working over it the next day, it gives me a connectivity issue which I resolve by Ctrl-C followed by that same `runserver` command again. Then it works normal again. Bear in mind that I do not lose connectivity to the internet of any sort( if it matters, I guess).

Is there a specific setting that keeps doing this and if yes how could I configure it so that I do not have to restart the server every day?

FYI, the python code and webpage work fine as expected. Just needed help so that I can avoid the every day task of restarting the server. I also do not receive any error logs that mention if my server was killed or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django server killed frequently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855652/django-server-killed-frequently)

Comment: I get the point of your answer in the link but I do not really get any error message saying Killed. Would there be a reason for that?

Comment: do not use `runserver` in production.

Comment: This is not in production. This is in my dev environment

Comment: Why does the development need to run "continuously"?..

Comment: project requirement. :(

Comment: ok looks like I need to use apache with uswgi

Comment: how can a project requirement dictate what the developer does on his machine??

Comment: ofcourse it cant haha. Thats why the developer(me) has decided to use apache with uswgi. Just needed some guidance and confirmation that running it 24x7 is out of scope. Thank You.