# Django is running on private ip instead of the public one, is it problematic?

Tags: django

I just configured basically a server and before installing gunicorn + nginx I wanted to try my django runserver.

So, I have a public IP and a private one.
My front (Simple index.html + react) is correctly deserving the public IP, but my django only pass by the private one when I start
`./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`

When I try:
`./manage.py runserver public.I.P:8080` I have this error:

`Error: That IP address can't be assigned to.`

Is that normal?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39855716/267540

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually assign public IP like this. When you are running "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80", it means Django server will accept all connections from all sources. For eg., if public IP of your server is 52.24.33.24 and you run Django server using "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80", then typing 52.24.33.24 in your browser should take you to your Django site.