# How to make a port live in windows using command line?

Tags: python, django, operating-system, port, live

I am running my django-python server on localhost and it gives following status while running:

`System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
January 04, 2017 - 19:58:23
Django version 1.9, using settings 'goldbrex.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:9000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.`

I want my fellow(windows user to hit an API running on localhost at my PC, How to make it possible using command line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39855716/267540

Answer (score 1):

You can't let others visit your site if you run your server on `127.0.0.1`, which is localhost only. I think you need to start your server like this:

```
manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9000
```

Then other people could grab your ip address(assume it's 1.2.3.4) and visit it in the browser:

```
1.2.3.4:9000
```

Check [wikipedia on what is `0.0.0.0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should run your django application on 0.0.0.0, so external users can connect to it

```
 python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9000
```

Then (assuming port 9000 is open in your firewall), your fellow developers can access your application using your IP address - you can figure it out using ifconfig command if you are on Linux.

For example, if your IP address is 129.1.1.1, they should use 129.1.1.1:9000

There are some gotchas with firewall and internal IP address, but that would be your first step.