# how to bring out django project from virtualenv

Tags: django, virtualenv

I have django project in virtualenv and now I am publishing it in server but the problem is I can not move project from virtualenv, when I do this then related packages inside site-package, cant be read and errors occur, how can I bring out my project from virtualenv without any issuing

Comment: Can't you create a new virtualenv on the server and match your project dependencies in it ?

Comment: I can create new virtualenv on the server, but I dont want to use virtualenv in server instead I wanna run project without virtualenv

Comment: Well you just need to install your dependencies on the server then. You can use pip freeze to get your dependencies as e4c5 said

Comment: From experience: never ever rely on system's libs and packages when deploying a Django (or whatever else Python-based) project. This __will__ break one day or another, unless you never do any update to the system anymore (which is not an option either).

Comment: Please be so kind as to mark the answer as correct in keeping with the standard practice here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new virtualenv on the server. It's easy

Step 1 Get the list of modules in the current virtualenv

```
source /path/to/current/bin/activate
pip freeze > /tmp/requirements.txt
```

Step 2 Create a new virtualenv. Login to your new server, copy the requirements file there. Then either change into a suitable directory before excuting the virtualenv command or give a full path.

```
 deactivate
 virtualenv -p python envname
```

Step 3 Install modules

```
source envname/bin/activate
pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

That's it.

As @bruno has pointed out, you really should be using a virtualenv on the server. And you should be using it on your local dev server as well. Then you can be really sure that the code will run at both ends without any surprises.

Comment: okey yes I can do this, but I dont want to use virtualenv, I want to run project outside the virtualenv

Comment: @huseyinozanhonamlioglu Why? Virtualenv does this well.

Comment: @huseyinozanhonamlioglu yes you _do_ want to use a virtualenv on your production server - that's how you garantee it will run on the expected environment and won't break whenever the sysadmin do any system update.

Comment: hımmm Okey so you saying the proper way to do it using virtualenv ? then okey I will do it that way.

Comment: Yes, this is the proper way (or at least one of the proper ways but certainly the simplest and best documented - specially if you already use a virtualenv for development).

Comment: thanks @brunodesthuilliers for the input. Corrected the typo

Comment: I was doing this job with apaches server but i switch django own server, and i already develop in virtualenv, so now i am gonna do it inside virtualenv

Comment: I don't really see how you exactly apache is related to this. When you say " i switch django own server", if you mean you are using the django development server in production. Don't!  see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855652/django-server-killed-frequently/39855716?s=1|0.7612#39855716

Comment: sorry about my pronouncing, sometimes I can misspelling words, sorry about that, but I solved my problem, and even using now with apache wsgi, and thanks for your ideas on the problem