# Django app does not load css files when run with supervsior

Tags: django, supervisord

I am running a simple hello world django app using supervisor. I was looking at this package in GitHub - https://github.com/rfk/django-supervisor for reference as well.

The app runs all okay, but when I load the index.html page, I see none of my CSS files being loaded and I just see plain-text. Do I need to add the css files as a specific program directory/file in the supervisord config?

Comment: You're running Django with supervisor, fine. But in production, Django isn't a static server. You need to rig your front-facing server like nginx to do that for you.

Comment: Do I need nginx even in development? I am just playing around in my local box.

Comment: In dev, you don't need Nginx. You might wanna check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181047/django-static-files-development

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855652/django-server-killed-frequently/39855716?s=1|0.7612#39855716

Comment: @e4c5: yeah, I am aware that the default server isn't production safe and it should never go into a production ready environment