# Is it normal that the Django site I recently deployed on Apache is always on?

Tags: python, django, apache, ssh

I recently deployed a Django site on a DigitalOcean droplet through Apache. I did `python manage.py runserver` through ssh and now the Django site is running. However, it stayed on even after the ssh session expired (understandable because it's still running on the remote server) but how do I shut it down if I need to?

Also, due to this, I don't get error messages on the terminal if something goes wrong like I do when I develop locally. What would be a fix for this?

Comment: Check if the process is running ps -aux |  grep runserver. Kill it with the pid. The logs are going on stdout . Never run it this way on production also, with Debug=True

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django server killed frequently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855652/django-server-killed-frequently)

Comment: @BipulJain I ran `ps -aux | grep runserver` and indeed there was one process but when I try to kill it with `kill -9 <process id>` I always get "No such process".

Comment: Why are you using `runserver` for your production?

Comment: Try this. ps -ax | grep 'runserver' | awk '{print $1}' | sudo xargs kill -9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is confusing. If you deployed it with Apache, it's running through Apache and not through runserver. You might have additionally started runserver, but that is not what is serving your site.

Comment: I see. I was not aware of this. Right, so how do I get error logs?

Comment: Probably in /var/log/apache2.