# Django lightweight development Web server can't run for a long time

Tags: django

**Django 1.11**

I decided to demonstrate what I have done to my friends. I have paid for hosting, installed nginx and proxied the requests to Django.

Then I went to the project directory and typed "python manage.py runserver".

Well, this is for demonstration purposes. It is not a production.

The problem is: in about half an hour the process disappeared. And nginx shows 502 Bad Gateway. When I run in Linux "ps aux | grep runserver", there is no development Web server running. So, it disappeared.

Why the process disappeares? Where can I find any settings to regulate the life time of this process?

Comment: It depends on your hosting solution, it may be was killed by some internal agent process, because of it could have memory leak, CPU leak etc.

Comment: The development server isn't designed to run continuously. You may want to deploy your app via modwsgi have a look at the guide here-> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Thank you. I'll relaunch with Gunicorn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django server killed frequently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855652/django-server-killed-frequently)