# Issue with django/postgresql when django started from cron

Tags: django, postgresql

Edit to ask who thought that this question had anything to do with the "possibly related" one.

I have a fairly simple django (1.11) project using the rest_framework that works fine when I start it from the command line, typing

```
nohup python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:4448 &
```

on centos. Connects to a postgresql database, with

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'my_database',
    'USER': 'my_user',
     #'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
     'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    ' PORT': '5432',
  }
}
```

in my `settings.py` file. However if I set up the runserver command to run at boot time from a cron I get the following when I send a request to the application:

```
... lot of stuff
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection 
refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

and in my pg_hba file I have

## IPv4 local connections:

```
host    all                     all                     127.0.0.1/32               
trust                     # local host
host    all                     all                     10.2.11.53/32                    
trust
host    all                     my_user                 0.0.0.0/0                       trust
```

and also I have

```
netstat -plunt | grep post
tcp        0      0 10.2.11.53:5432         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
        867/postmaster      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
        867/postmaster
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks,

a

PS The full traceback:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x1a11230>
Performing system checks...

[<RegexURLPattern batch-batch-done ^batch/batch-done/$>, <RegexURLPattern batch-load-urls ^batch/load-urls/$>, <RegexURLPattern batch-request-batch ^batch/request-batch/$>, <RegexURLPattern batch-schedule-job ^batch/schedule-job/$>]
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 128, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 422, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 209, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: Why are you running the development server from cron? In a production environment you should use a real wsgi server, managed by your system's process manager (eg systemd).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django server killed frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855652/django-server-killed-frequently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you post the full traceback, as well as the cron job itself?

Also, if I understand your question correctly, you are trying to use cron to start your server on boot? If this is the case, you would be better served using something like supervisord to manage your server processes IMO.

Comment: Full traceback: Looks like I can't remove the comment. What's the best way to post the traceback. Too big for the comment section.

Comment: You probably need to edit your original post (comments would be too small to put a traceback in)

Comment: Didn't find out why my set up didn't work (I actually inherited it from someone else), but using supervisor was a huge improvement, easier that I though it would be. And solved the issue.